# Java: Parsing Strings with extra quotes

Tags: java, string, split

Alternate problem title: Splitting a comma delimited list that is inside of a tab delimited list.

I'm looking for a solution that does not involve other packages other
than standard java routines. This has got to be something that has
been solved before, I just don't know which keywords to use on
Stackoverflow to find it!

I have a tab delimited file that I am parsing. I perform error checking on the fields after splitting the line to prevent bad data getting into my program. I pretty much have everything solved except for one field. The basic layout of the input line is:

```
field1<tab>field2<tab>field3<tab>field4
```

field3, by design can contain:

1. Empty string:

   ```
   field1<tab>field2<tab><tab>field4
   ```
2. One string, with or without blanks:

   ```
   field1<tab>field2<tab>Fred Flintstone<tab>field4
   ```
3. Multiple strings separated by commas:

   ```
   field1<tab>field2<tab>Fred, Barney, Wilma<tab>field4
   ```

The line is read and split as follows:

```
    String entry = pq2File.readline();
    String[] temp;
    temp = entry.split("\t", 4);
```

When I split the input line by "\t" my third field (temp[2]) is set equal as follows in each of the cases above:

1. []
2. [Fred Flintstone]
3. [Fred, Barney, Wilma]

I then split field3 again by ","

```
ArrayList<String> names = 
     new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(temp[2].split(",")));
```

giving me the following values in the ArrayList names, in each of the cases above

1. [empty]
2. Fred Flintstone
3. Fred
    Barney
    Wilma

All this is handled correctly when I use text editor to create the file, or SQL statements to pull the data out of an external, remote system to which I do not have access. The problem comes in with a user that insists on using MS EXCEL to create the file. In this case the line looks like this:

```
field1<tab>field2<tab>"Fred, Barney, Wilma"<tab>field4
```

When I parse the line, my variable gets the value

```
"Fred, Barney, Wilma"
```

And splitting it by "," results in:
   "Fred
   Barney
   Wilma"

Obviously I want to get rid the extra " marks. Am I looking for a solution to remove the " marks before I split the field? or does it make more sense (less code) to wait until after the field is split, and then just look at the first and last items.  I ask because it is possible that the line could be:

```
field1<tab>field2<tab>"Fred Flintstone", "Barney Rubble", "Wilma Flintstone"<tab>field4
```

In this case I would expect temp[2] to become:

```
"Fred Flintstone", "Barney Rubble", "Wilma Flintstone"
```

and the resulting split of temp[2] should result in:
"Fred Flintstone"
"Barney Rubble"
"Wilma Flintstone"

which would be fine.

**Edit**
The design team has been consulted and confirmed that for ALL fields, there can be no embedded tabs within the fields.

Further, they have confirmed that within field 3, there can be no embedded commas with an item within the field.

therefore, input such as:

```
field1<tab>field2<tab>"Fred Flintstone", "Barney, Wilma"<tab>field4
```

should result in three entries for field3:

- "Fred Flintstone"
- "Barney
- Wilam"

I am pressing them on another issue that may make this whole issue moot...

Comment: You might wanna think about using escape characters, like \"

Comment: If you mean the input, I have no control over the input. or are you suggesting something else that is obvious that I'm just overlooking?

Comment: Do you mean 'comma-delimited list'? And don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: I think in the case for `<tab>"Fred Flintstone", "Barney Rubble", "Wilma Flintstone"<tab>` there would be a set of enclosing quotes around that column. At least based on the example transition from `<tab>Fred, Barney, Wilma<tab>` to `<tab>"Fred, Barney, Wilma"<tab>`

Comment: cricket_007, again it depends on who is providing the input. If it was coming from MS-Excel, I would agree with you. But as some data comes from sql statements, and others are coming from either text editors or other programs, we can't assume that the entire "column" would be surrounded by quotes. Again, the data comes from multiple inputs.

Comment: Sure. I would be concerned if your fields could also contain tabs

Comment: cricket_007: yep that could be a problem. We dodged that bullet by definition of the fields and that fields cannot contain tabs. if they do the input file is rejected. Maybe not the most flexible design, but a design decision was made.

Comment: The fields cannot contain tags, OK. But would they contain commas? A full quoted name like _"Obama, Barak"_ should be regarded as _one_ or _two_ tokens?

Comment: Little Santi: Good question (I raised it as well in one of the "answers" before... At this point the design says no, within in field3 there can be no commas or tabs as part of the field. I will update the original quest to address this.

Comment: @erickson thanks for the catching the spelling mistakes. I do in fact know the difference between "comma" and "common" as well as "mute" and "moot". It seems my auto spell checker likes to change things without telling me!

Comment: @EJP I didn't understand your comment, until I realized you edited my post. Yes, I do mean comma delimited list, that's what I wrote, as I have in my original composing notes. Somewhere along the line one of the "auto spelling correct" routines must have changed it. As the source I did the cut and paste from has "comma" in it. As for the quote formatting, I was only trying to highlight something similar to the help square when adding these comments. Without using bold, italic, etc. I wasn't aware that this was frowned upon. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want to

- Split by comma
- If ((first element starts with double-quote but does not end with double-_quote) and (last element ends with double-quote but does not start with double-quote)) then remove those doble-quotes

Still, I am wondering if there can be bad data, like

```
field1<tab>field2<tab>"Fred Flintstone", "Barney, Wilma"<tab>field4
```

Resulting in all kinds of dirty data. You might want rigorously define the grammar instead of using examples, at which point the parsing should become trivial.

Comment: This is what I think I'm leaning towards. not pretty, doesn't handle all the weird cases like a comm inside of double quotes i.e. something like:   field1<tab>field2<tab>"Fred", Wilma, "Bambam, Pebbels, and Dino"<tab>field4.... But it does solve the immediate problem with my favorite "errant" users :)

Comment: One option is to always strip the quotes, optionally adding them around every sub-field again.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to code a *specific parser* in two levels:

- The outer level should stop at every occurrence of TAB.
- The inner level should stop at every occurrence of comma, and discard first character quote and last character quote.

And not to sound so theoretically, I post here my proposal:

```
public class CombinedStringParser
{
    private final String src;

    private final char delimitter;

    private int currentPos=0;

    public CombinedStringParser(String src, char delimitter)
    {
        super();
        this.src=src;
        this.delimitter=delimitter;
    }

    public String nextToken()
    {
        int initialPos=this.currentPos;
        int x=0;
        while (this.currentPos < this.src.length())
        {
            char c=this.src.charAt(this.currentPos++);
            if (c == this.delimitter)
            {
                x=-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return this.src.substring(initialPos, this.currentPos + x);
    }

    public List<String> nextListOfTokens(char listDelimitter)
    {
        int initialPos=this.currentPos;
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        while (this.currentPos < this.src.length())
        {
            char c=this.src.charAt(this.currentPos++);
            if (c == this.delimitter)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (c == listDelimitter)
                {
                    int p1=initialPos;
                    int p2=this.currentPos - 1;
                    if (this.src.charAt(p1) == '\"')
                    {
                        p1++;
                    }
                    if (this.src.charAt(p2 - 1) == '\"')
                    {
                        p2--;
                    }
                    list.add(this.src.substring(p1, p2));
                    initialPos=this.currentPos;
                }
            }
        }
        if (initialPos < this.currentPos)
        {
            int p1=initialPos;
            int p2=this.src.length();
            if (this.src.charAt(p1) == '\"')
            {
                p1++;
            }
            if (this.src.charAt(p2 - 1) == '\"')
            {
                p2--;
            }
            list.add(this.src.substring(p1, p2));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
CombinedStringParser parser=new CombinedStringParser(src, '\t');
String firstToken=parser.nextToken();
String secondToken=parser.nextToken();
List<String> thirdToken=parser.nextListOfTokens(',');
String fourthToken=parser.nextToken();
```

Appart from being *effective*, thanks to its specificity this solution is also *efficient*, because it parses each character *just once*.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the " first, then split.

```
temp = entry.replaceAll("\"", '').split("\t", 4);
```

Comment: This would not work in the last example. where field3 is actually three comma delimited values, each with quotes around them (presumably due to other characters that could cause problems later on. This is why simply eliminating all "'s does not work.